I would to extract table values from a JSON field on Oracle SQL
I am having some issues on extracting data from a field called "JSON" which is a clob inside a table in Oracle SQL.
For example, i have a table called Pippo which has the following data:
id : 1,2,3
Value : a, b, c
And I have inside my table called "JSON_TEST" my JSON field which has the following format : {"from: "Pippo"}
I would to use the JSON function to make a query (or function) that have takes my table from the JSON field and return Pippo's values.
like : Select * (from JSON field).
In other words, i would to extract Pippo's values from the JSON present inside JSON_TEST

You would need PL/SQL to generate dynamic SQL for that. SQL does not support dynamically generating the name of the table you are querying.

@MT0 yes, do you know where i can find some documentation or examples?

@Mariomaxi What version of Oracle are you using? And will the number and data types of the relevant columns always be the same for each table? (The version determines what solutions are available, like PL/SQL CTE, Polymorphic table functions, SQL macros, etc.)

@JonHeller I am using oracle 21. The number of columns and datatype is different for each table.
